# Python: Finding the contours of an image or 2D array

Tags: python, opencv

## The Task

I want to find the contour of data in a numpy array.

Here is the sample data:

```
data = array([
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3]], dtype=uint8)
```

## The Issue

I almost succeed in, but it is slightly offset:

[image]

**As you can clearly see, there is an offset!** How can I remove it??

## What I have done so far

```
def find_contours(int_data):
    
    # For every "color" in the dataset find the contour
    # by eliminating all the other colors one after each other and finding the 
    # individual contours
    contours = []
    
    
    for color in np.unique(int_data):
      
        # Create temporary canvas, and 
        # set all entries equal to 1 that have the same postion as the 
        # original color
        
        mask = np.zeros_like(int_data)
        mask[int_data == color] = 1 # white object on black background
        
        c, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        contours.append(c)
    
    return contours
```

Using the function defined above:

```
contours = find_contours(data)

## Draw 
for contour in contours:
    
    coords = np.reshape(contour[0].flatten(), (-1,2))
    x = list(coords[:,0])
    x.append(x[0])
    
    y = list(coords[:,1])
    y.append(y[0])
    plt.plot(x,y)


plt.imshow(data, origin="lower")
```

## EDIT:

By replacing the contour finding algorithm:

```
from skimage import measure

# REPLACE in function
c = measure.find_contours(mask)
```

To plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.gray, origin="lower")

for contour in contours:
    contour = contour[0]
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1]-1, contour[:, 0]-1, linewidth=2)



plt.show()
```

[image]

... but the corners are still cut off. *Any ideas of how to fix it?*

Comment: OpenCV quirk. their contours are supposed to roundtrip with drawContours, which draws lines directly on the points, so this requires contours to go _on top_ of the inner boundary pixels of blobs, not directly on the boundary (between pixels). -- fixing this would require "offsetting" by half a pixel or so -- perhaps use something from scipy or skimage or whatever, because OpenCV doesn't, to my knowledge, have any way to "fix" these contours

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Many thanks for your comment! Would you know how to achieve such an offset? I was thinking to do that, but could not find a viable way.

Comment: I'd recommend to look for something to replace opencv's contour finding. skimage has find_contours but IDK how comparable that is. -- if you're choosing to stick with OpenCV's findContours, you'll have to fix up the contours, which is tricky. the "offset" operation is generally called a "Minkowski sum". the usual "kernel" (other polygon) is a circle because that's most well-behaved. there exists scikit-geometry. not sure how helpful that is, don't know the library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Many thanks for your answer. Please see the updated question. We are almost there... Do you know how to solve this corner issue?

Comment: oh interesting, skimage has quirks too! docs say "marching squares", which explains a few things. in that case, there's little you can do. you could try messing with the `fully_connected` parameter (the others don't look interesting). -- there may be ways to rewrite the result of marching squares, change those corner cutting instances to be rectangular. it's late, I can't think about that now. -- most probably you might have to write something based on marching squares yourself. shouldn't be difficult.